# Is TP-LINK TD-W8151N vulnerable to KRACK?

Tags: wifi, wireless, router, wpa2, krack

I have a [TP-LINK TD-W8151N](http://www.tp-link.com/il/products/details/cat-15_TD-W8151N.html) 150Mbps Wireless N ADSL2+ Modem Router.
Is this model vulnerable to KRACK?
It is not specified in the [WPA2 Security (KRACKs) Vulnerability Statement](http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-1970.html). Will TP-Link publish firmware updates for this model?

Comment: Wow this is specific, why don't you use [TP-Link forum](http://forum.tp-link.com) for this question instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can neither see support for 802.11r (fast roaming) nor support for repeater mode in [the specification](http://www.tp-link.com/il/products/details/cat-15_TD-W8151N.html#specifications). Based on this the AP is probably not affected but probably only the vendor itself can you the ultimate answer about it. See also the statement of TP-Link regarding a specific type of routers and use case which is part of the vulnerability statment you've linked to:

> Unaffected TP-Link products:
>   ...
>   Routers and gateways working in their default mode (Router Mode) and AP Mode